# Hyperlinking to Facebook iframe application without knowing page name

Tags: facebook, facebook-iframe

I have a Facebook iframe app that runs on various Facebook pages. I can create a link directly to my app with the following hyperlink:

http://www.facebook.com/pages/PAGE-NAME/PAGE-ID?sk=app_APP-ID
where **PAGE-NAME**, **PAGE-ID**, and **APP-ID** are populated with their corresponding variables.

Is there a way to link to my app if I don't know the **PAGE-NAME**, and only know **PAGE-ID** and my **APP-ID**?

I can link to the page without knowing the PAGE-NAME using the following hyperlink:
www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=**PAGE-ID**

However I can't seem to find a way to link to my app's iframe on the page. I've tried these 2 links but they don't work either:

www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=**PAGE-ID**&sk=app_**APP-ID**
www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=**PAGE-ID**&v=app_**APP-ID**

Comment: Just realized that the www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=PAGE-ID doesn't work either

Comment: Can you use server-side language?

Comment: i know of a solution with graph api but in this case looking for url syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://graph.facebook.com/**PAGE_ID**

json_decode that, get the **LINK** field.

append your

?sk=app_**APP-ID**